# Setting path/gem_home in combination with 'bundler/inline', rbenv and a global ruby

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

In a quest to make ruby scripts that are standalone and portable, I'm using `bundler/inline`.

The servers that I provision this script to, are pretty specific, they have rbenv (so we can rollback/use multiple ruby versions) and since the time it costs to install certain gems (backup gem). We use a global ruby install.

Resulting in scripts with 'bundle/inline' executed by a non root user throwing an error:

```
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:  

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.
```

Sadly bundler/inline doesn't have an option to give this as an argument.

So I tried to resolve this by setting the bundle path: `bundle config path ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/`, but this doesn't work. (I checked and the config is properly saved)

Setting  `GEM_HOME=~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/` does work. (Ruby gems supports two gem home's for this scenario, so this actually works fine). The only problem is that I need to do some bookkeeping in keeping that environment variable in line with the minor version of the ruby activated by rbenv. I cannot set this ENV from my ruby script, where I can easily calculate this version based on the current version:

```
version_used_for_gem_home = RUBY_VERSION.gsub /\.\d+$/, '.0'
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = "/var/lib/postgresql/.gem/ruby/#{version_used_for_gem_home}/"
require 'bundler/inline'
```

Is there a better solution that doesn't require me to do any bookkeeping? I would love to have some rbenv hooks I can use to modify the path/gem home...

Answer (score 3):

We just had the same problem, and I discovered this does the trick

```
require 'bundler/inline'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.configure # where the magic happens
# passing true here does the install; in real scripts we
# pass a boolean based on a --install flag.
gemfile(true) do 
   ...gems go here...
end
```

You need to explicitly call `Bundler.configure` to get it to read your bundle config, and set up the paths correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue: I want to distribute a single file that requires non-default gems from rubygems and is supposed to be run as a non-root user.

Fortunately, while `bunder/inline` is API-less to the point of annoyance, by requiring `bundler` (as recommended by @bazzargh) we get a lot more API. Not a convenient or documented API (*), mind you, but you can get things to work.

My solution looks like this:

```rb
require 'bundler/inline'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.configure_gem_home_and_path "#{ENV['HOME']}/.cache/my-app-bundle"
gemfile do
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'my-gem'
end
```

Notes:

- `~/.cache/my-app-bundle` is where I want bundler to install the gems.
- Because we don't set `gemfile(true)`, the `bundler install` process only runes once (if any gems are missing) and produces no output. This is what I need for a CLI, but YMMV.

---

*) Want to know how to operate `Bundler`? Go to [the annoyingly useless `Bundler` module reference on ruby-lang.org](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Bundler.html) and start reading the source.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here is the simplest thing that works for me:

```rb
Gem.paths = { "GEM_HOME" => Gem.user_dir }
require "bundler/inline"
```

`Gem.paths=` takes an `ENV`-like object. If you have other Gem-related environment variables that you want to take effect, you might need:

```rb
Gem.paths = ENV.merge({ "GEM_HOME" => Gem.user_dir })`
require "bundler/inline"
```

(Both [the answer by bazzargh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596129/198420) and [the answer by Guss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74041520/198420) fail for me with `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)`. Maybe Bundler has changed since the answers were posted, or they were trying this in an environment where Bundler was able to find a Gemfile.)